# Cannot implicitly convert type "void" to "bool"

Tags: unity, c#

I have a problem with pressing UI button while cursor is locked. I tried to write in the script so that the cursor unlocks when a button appears on the screen, but the error "Cannot implicitly convert type "void" to "bool"" appeared. I searched for a solution on the Internet, but none of the solutions I found helped me.

```
public GameObject button;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    LockCursor();
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
    if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Escape))
    {
        UnlockCursor();
    }

    if(Input.GetMouseButton(0))
    {
        LockCursor();
    }

    if(button.SetActive(true))
    {
        UnlockCursor();
    }
}

private void LockCursor()
{
    Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
    Cursor.visible = false;
}

private void UnlockCursor()
{
    Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.None;
    Cursor.visible = true;
}
```

What can I do to solve this issue?
Thanks for any help!

Comment: button.SetActive(true) is a function call, returning nothing -> can't be used as a check for condition -> what the error says, you get nothing back aka void and your condition needs to be either true or false.

Comment: This is a basic language type error. You should always search for such errors on our general programming sister site StackOverflow - [you'll find many existing Q&A posts about it](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=convert+void+to+bool&mixed=0), so you don't have to ask a new one.

Answer (score 1):

I have found a solution. In this case, the ".activeSelf" function is required. This function checks if the object is active or not and returns local active state of the GameObject.